# jquery popup form and codeigniter framework

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I'm trying to develop a system using Codeigniter, i tell you what i want problem is i don't know how to achieve it, and tried to find tutorials it didn't worked out either! :(

I'm displaying the data from a MySql table as a list in my user interface, there is a separate link for each list entry, when the user click on that link a form should appear, a pop-up form and user should be able to fill some fields by typing, it also should display the already filled table columns values unique to that entry of the table and user is given opportunity to add data to a blank cells in that row!when user submits it data should go to the table and update it! i want to achieve this functionality guys! please give me any advice you can, tutorial links, code anything to achieve this!

regards,
Rangana

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) and post to the server using jQuery's $.post function.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Dialog in JQuery UI - here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

You can create a hidden div and then use jQuery load on this div for every link and then create a dialog from this hidden div. Works well for me.